# How select the previous option with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html page with a select element like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="ExSelect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
 </select>
  <br>
  <br>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <button onclick="ToTheNext()" id="btnext">Next</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And I'm using this simple function on the button OnClick to change the selected item to the next option item of the dropdown:

```
function ToTheNext()
{
    $('#ExSelect option:selected').next().attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

My question is: How can i change the selected item to the previous option of this  tag using `Vanilla JavaScript` or `jQuery`?

Jsbin Example: https://jsbin.com/nuyeduf/edit?html,js,output

Comment: just use `prev()` instead of `next()`

Comment: Like @ToniMichelCaubet said, just use `prev()` instead of `next()`

Comment: and .prop('selected', true) instead of .attr('selected', 'selected');

Comment: I'm feeling very dumb right now.......

Comment: @Pv-Viana We've been there :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two problems - first by using `attr` you're setting more than one option to selected, which is probably not what you want to do as it will stop the `prev()` from working as you expect.

Change your code like this:

```
function ToTheNext()
{
    $('#ExSelect option:selected').next().prop('selected', true);
}

function ToThePrevious()
{
    $('#ExSelect option:selected').prev().prop('selected', true);
}
```

https://jsbin.com/xewopobasi/1/edit?html,js,output

If you're using jQuery then stop using `onclick` attributes and instead assign click handlers appropriately

```
$('#btnext').on('click', function(){
    $('#ExSelect option:selected').next().prop('selected', true);
});
```

```js
$(function(){

  $('#btnext').on('click',function(){
    $('#ExSelect option:selected').next().prop('selected', true);
  });

  $('#btprev').on('click',function(){
    $('#ExSelect option:selected').prev().prop('selected', true);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ExSelect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
 </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="btnext">Next</button>
  <button id="btprev">Prev</button>
```

Comment: I used the onclick attribute only in this example. Thanks for the very good answer!

Answer (score 3):

Replace the `.attr('selected', 'selected');` with `.prop('selected', true);`

`next()` with `prev()`

and add the `jQuery` script under the button.

```js
const select = $('#ExSelect');

function next()
{
   select.find('option:selected').next().prop('selected', true);
}

function prev()
{
  select.find('option:selected').prev().prop('selected', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ExSelect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
</select>
<button onclick="next()" id="btnext">Next</button>
<button onclick="prev()" id="btprev">Prev</button>
```

Comment: Maybe you mean `prop()`?

Comment: No, `prev` finds the previous of the first match, which means by using `attr` it wont work.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$('#ExSelect option:selected').prev().prop('selected', true);`

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete the answer. If you want to trigger something with the new selected option, you must add .change() at the end of your functions :

```
function ToTheNext(){
    $('#ExSelectoption:selected').next().prop('selected', true).change();
}

function ToThePrevious(){
    $('#ExSelectoption:selected').prev().prop('selected', true).change();
}
```